# How to Format a Phone Number

Tags: android, regex

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

If a phone number is entered as 6123044356 it will display as (612)304-4356. Should a guest hit the backspace key 5 times instead of removing the last 4 numbers entered and the dash, remove the last 5 numbers entered. The phone number at that point would be displayed as (612)30. Should the guest hit the backspace key 3 more times the last 3 numbers displayed would be removed, not the parenthesis. The phone number would then be displayed as 61.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) library. It has AsYouTypeFormatter class in it, which will handle this for you.

Alternatively you can use [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html) which basically does the same thing. You would use it like so:

```
editText.addTextChangeListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it just like the dialer does it. That way is most intuitive.

Basically when they are typing, as soon as a number, say 1234567, gets to 7 digits, split it up like 123-4567 for the user. Then when it reaches 10 digits, 123-4567890, split it up like (123)456-7890 for them. When they reach 11 digits, change the format to 1-(234)567-8901.

When they are removing numbers from an 11 digit number, as soon as they hit 10 digits, change back to (123)456-7890. After that, as soon as the number of digits is less than 10, change the format back to 123-456789. Keep it in that format until they reach six digits when you just change it to 123456.

By changing the numbers to and from recognizable forms when a user reaches a certain number of digits, it subtly alerts the user that they have either created a real number, or there are too many or not enough digits for this to be a real number.

I suggest using the following thresholds:

- 11 digits: 1-(234)567-8901
- 10 digits: (123)456-7890 (anything less than this looks like 7 digits with digits on the end)
- 7 digits: 123-4567 (anything less just removes the dash).

I hope that makes sense. I do not think the user should have to input/erase any extra characters like parentheses and dashes. It should all be taken care of by the app.

Comment: I realize that I want to know how to do that though using code.